# WPF Dialog Inside Excel Addin. Issues with Focus

Tags: c#, excel, wpf, excel-dna

I have an Excel add-in that I built with ExcelDNA and C#. The add-in utilizes the Essential Objects Browser within a WPF dialog. However, I'm encountering an issue when attempting to change the focus from the WPF dialog to an Excel worksheet. Whenever I click on a cell, the cell is selected and changed, but the focus remains on the dialog. This causes any input to go to the dialog instead of the cell. Interestingly, if I click anywhere else other than the cells, the focus is correctly set to the Excel dialog. I'm wondering if there are any specific properties on the WPF object that I need to set to address this issue.

I've also observed that when the WPF dialog is active and I hover over cells, the cursor changes to a cross. However, when other dialogs are active, the cursor over the cells remains as a pointer, and the focus changes correctly upon clicking.

Comment: Is it your intention that the dialog be modal?

Comment: The dialog needs to be a separate window.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want display the window as modal perhaps you can try to display it as `ICustomTaskPane` and set its property `DockPosition` to `MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionFloating`:

```
        public void ShowPane(IRibbonControl control)
        {
            if (ExcelDnaUtil.IsInFunctionWizard())
            {
                return;
            }
             // ... other code

            ICustomTaskPane_pane = CustomTaskPaneFactory.CreateCustomTaskPane(typeof(YourWindow), "YourName");
            _pane.DockPosition = MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionFloating;
        }
```